# Find a function given equation $x(1+x)y''+ (k + (l + m + 1)x)y'+kly = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am really stuck with the problem below.

I have the following differential equation:
$$x(1+x)y''+ (k + (l + m + 1)x)y'+kly = 0$$
I need to find such functions $\alpha(x)$ and $I(\alpha(x))$ for which $z''+I(x)z=0$, where $z(x)=\frac{y(x)}{\alpha(x)}$.

I first tried to find a particular solution for the first equation in the form of $y=Ax^2+Bx+C$:

$$x(1+x)\times 2A+(k + (l + m + 1)x)\times (2Ax+B)+kl\times (Ax^2+Bx+C) = 0$$

Which transforms to:

$$\bbox[lightgreen, 5px]{2Ax}+\bbox[pink, 4px]{2Ax^2}+\bbox[lightgreen, 5px]{2Akx}+\bbox[pink, 2px]{2A(l+m+1)x^2}+\bbox[lightblue, 5px]{Bk}+\bbox[lightgreen, 3px]{B(l+m+1)x}+\bbox[pink, 5px]{Aklx^2}+\bbox[lightgreen, 5px]{Bklx}+\bbox[lightblue, 5px]{Ckl}=0 $$

Which leads to the following system of equations:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
2A+2A(l+m+1)+Akl&=0 \\ 
2A + 2Ak + B(l+m+1)+Bkl &=0 \\ 
Bk+Ckl&=0 
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
And I can't find a solution for this system.

Did I choose the right way to solve the problem? Did I identify the type of the differetial eqiaton correctly?
Or should I probably start by first solving $z''+I(x)z=0$?

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Could the downvoter explain his/her reasoning? The OP is new here, so if you think this post can be improved, please leave a comment.

Comment: Hi, the solution to your equation leads to a hypergeometric function

Comment: Are you interested in a Maple solution?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thank you for the hint! I'll try to figure it out from this point. Maple will not do in this case as this is a demo problem for an exam where I may not use anything.